# How to track keywords or links which redirects on 404 using htacess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, seo

I am trying to track the keywords or links that lead to my site 404 page. I am redirecting using htaccess. Is there any way to done this?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^404 ./404.php
```

Comment: analyze log files.

Comment: i want to store them in db for  reporting these url's or tags to admin.